# Global Variables in C#

Tags: c#

Can someone perhaps help me with a little problem I have on my database application.

When a user logs into my database with a User Name and Password, I want the User Name to be stored and accesible by the application as a whole (all forms etc), so that every action undertaken carries the users signature as it were.

I'm thinking the code is probably something like the following:

```
namespace YourNamespaceName
{
    class Variables
    {
        public static string strUser = "user name";
    }
}
```

Which I can recall then with Variables.strUser

However I don't want to hard code the value of user name into my application.  Rather I need it to be evaluated at runtime based on the initial log in procedure, and retain the user name for reference for the duration of the application running.

Thanking you all in anticipation of your assistance.

Comment: It's a variable - just assign whatever fits to it.

Comment: Like this:  YourNamespaceName.Variables.strUser = "Jimmy";

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
namespace YourNamespaceName
{
    public static class Variables
    {
        private static string strUser;


        public static string User {
           get { return strUser; }
           set { strUser = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

You didn't specify framework version, but this code works with .NET 2.0.  To use:

```
Variables.User = "User name";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a user class like below, this ensures that there is only a single instance of user in the application see Instance property and test stub for usage details, you can add more properties to the class if you wish.

```
    using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;

        namespace yournamespace
        {
          public class User
          {
           private static User u;
           public string Username
           { get { return _username; } }

           private string _username;
           protected User(){}

          public void SetUserInformation(string uname)
          {

           _username = uname;

          }

         public static User Instance
         {
          get{
           if(u==null)
             u=new User();
           return u;
          }
        }

#if(TEST_USER)
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      User u = User.Instance;
      u.SetUserInformation("testuser");
      User u1 = User.Instance;
    }
#endif
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your application maintains a session state, then your best solution is to have the variable live in the session and access it from session scoped variables

Comment: I don't think it's asp.net, it's win forms.

Comment: Yes its a win forms app - and I have no idea what you mean by session state or session scoped variables :s

Comment: My bad session refers to the duration of a transaction, so if you maintain a session state (for instance, the duration of a connection with your database can be your session.) you would maintain a collection of variables that are valid only for the duration of that session, which you would clean upon invalidation of the session. But this is probably beyond the scope of what you need so I would go with the other suggestions in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You could creAte some kind of a 'user' class to store the user information, such as username, password, email, etc...

You can implement this class as a singleton and creAte it once the user logs in for the first time.

Then whenever you need user information you can use the 'user' singleton class.

Answer (score 0):

For user identity you shoud use `IIdentity` interface. You can start with `GenericIdentiry`.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9dd5fx0.aspx for details.